# How to get PHP echo value in html, so it is the same as other inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, html, api

i will just present my example, because i dont know how to explain it thurrow.

Here is a html code with javascript, that calculates the numbers between themselves: http://jsbin.com/OJOlARe/1/edit?html,js,output

What i want to do, is replace the "input id="box2" " with the result i get with this code in PHP.

```
<?php

$url = "https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd";
$decode = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$price = $decode["btc_usd"]["last"];


echo $price;
?>
```

So i will input a value i want in box 1, the box2 will automaticly have the value of "echo $price" and the result will calculate these two between themselves.

Thank you very much for your help and efforts.

Comment: Use an ajax request.

Comment: How you want to do it that matters ? If you want to use ajax, It will be different and without ajax It will be different .

Comment: Btw why you need to change id of element? .. Isnt better way to use `data-id` attribute?

Comment: I dont really care how i will do it, just that it will work :D. So the BOX2 will have a value without me putting one in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this if I've understood it correctly.

PHP

```
<?php

$url = "https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd";
$decode = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$price = $decode["btc_usd"]["last"];


echo $price;
?>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Box 1</th>
    <th>Box 2</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="box2" value="<?php echo($price); ?>" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="result" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
        result.value = myResult;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Doesnt work. The value is still only what i put in. If i put nothing in box2 there is no value inside :(

Comment: What I understood is that you would like to take the value extracted from https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd and put it in the box2, so that the user would just have to fill box1.

If this is wrong, could you please re-explain it ?

Would you like to have the user to have just box1 and the result ?

Comment: Yes exactly, but there is no value inside box2 when i run everything(no value from btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd ). Only if i input something in myself.

Comment: That's weird, because when I load the code that I've sent you above and don't do anything else, the box2 is already filled.
http://i.imgur.com/JCTju6Y.png

Comment: Oh, i guess there is something else wrong with my code than. Thank you for your help, i will look around to see what is causing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get the value of price just add value . like so

try this.

```
 <td><input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"/></td>
```

Comment: Doesnt work. The value is still only what i put in. If i put nothing in box2 there is no value inside :(

Answer (score 0):

l3aronsansgland's suggestion will work. Rather then using a HTML file, I created a PHP file and placed all of the scripts inside it, as below. I've tested it and it worked fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <?php

$url = "https://btc-e.com/api/3/ticker/btc_usd";
$decode = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$price = $decode["btc_usd"]["last"];
?>

<script>
    function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
        result.value = myResult;
    }
</script>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<table width="80%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Box 1</th>
    <th>Box 2</th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="box2" value="<?php echo($price); ?>" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td><input id="result" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```